# Programmatically add Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add a new LinearLayout with a EditText element in it whenever a button on my app gets pushed. The xml I have is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/app"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:weightSum="1">
   <EditText android:id="@+id/dish_name"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="58dp"
      android:hint="@string/dish_name"
      android:background="@drawable/my_border"
      android:paddingLeft="10dip"/>
      <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ingredient_list"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="58dp"
         android:weightSum="1"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
         <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="42dp"
             android:hint="@string/edit_message"
             android:background="@drawable/my_border"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:paddingLeft="10dip"/>
         <Button
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/button_send"
             android:onClick="sendMessage" />
       </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to duplicate the second LinearLayout along with the EditText inside of it. The java code I have so far is:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
   LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    layout.setWeightSum(1f);
    params.weight = 1.0f;


    params.setMargins(0,20,0,0);

    EditText editText = new EditText(this);

    editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_border);
    editText.setHint(R.string.edit_message);
    editText.setLayoutParams(params);

    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.app);
    container.addView(editText);

}
```

The problem I am running into is that when I click the button I get the following:

[AppImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ete7.png)

I want the EditText box to be the same height as the one I have defined in the xml but it takes up the entire screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: remove *layout.setWeightSum(1f);params.weight = 1.0f;*

Answer (score 3):

No need to re-define the layout entirely within Java. You should define it as its own XML file. Call it `ingredient_input.xml`

For example, feel free to modify. This is one "row" for the EditText and button, so a horizontal layout. Could also be a RelativeLayout.

```
  <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="58dp"
     android:weightSum="1"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
     <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="42dp"
         android:hint="@string/edit_message"
         android:background="@drawable/my_border"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:paddingLeft="10dip"/>
     <Button
         android:id="@+id/btnAddMore"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/button_send"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

First, you need to get the parent linear layout

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ingredient_list);
```

Then, you can inflate the XML file for the "input row"

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this); // some context
View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ingredient_input, null);
```

You can also find the button, then set its click listener

```
row.findViewById(R.id.btnAddMore).setOnClickListener(...); // TODO
```

Then, just add that view onto the parent linear layout

```
ll.addView(row);
```

Realistically, you really could be using a ListView with an Adapter instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

In the code above, you have the height set to `match_parent` and widht set to `wrap_content`. Instead, try setting the height and the width to match your xml. The height should be `58dp` and the width should be match parent.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't the time to test this but you can try:

```
// assuming you have variables for ingredient_list and edit_message
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)ingredientList.getLayoutParams();
LinearLayout.LayoutParams editTextParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)editMessage.getLayoutParams();
```

You can then use these instead of creating the parameters.

P.S. you don't have a specified orientation in your ingredient_list in the xml.